# p5 collision detection with two arrays does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, collision-detection, p5.js

Good morning,

I am trying to do a collision detection between two objects from different arrays. 
I tried to use two for loops, but that does not work as seedArray() is undefined.

that is my code:

```
for (let i in seedArray) {
    for (let j in monsterArray) {
        if (
            seedArray[i].x > monsterArray[j].x &&
            seedArray[i].x + seedArray[i].radius <
            monsterArray[j].x + monsterWidth &&
            seedArray[i].y > monsterArray[j].y &&
            seedArray[i].y + seedArray[i].radius < monsterArray[j].y + monsterHeight
        ) {
            gameEnd();
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're using the `for..in` statement, which i don't think you need in this scenario.

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an
>   object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols),
>   including inherited enumerable properties. [find out more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

What you need is the `for..of` statement:

```
for (let seed of seedArray) {
    for (let monster of monsterArray) {
        if (
            seed.x > monster.x &&
            seed.x + seed.radius <
            monster.x + monsterWidth &&
            seed.y > monster.y &&
            seed.y + seed.radius < monster.y + monsterHeight
        ) {
            gameEnd();
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```